# Проблема с лайтбоксом

Tags: jquery

Всем привет.

Установил на сайт обычный плагин Slimbox 2 для отображения больших изображений по клику во всплывающем окне.

У меня есть статичные изображения вида, с ними проблем нет, все работает.

```
<a class="itogdetimg" href="" rel="lightbox" title=""><img width="83px" src="/img.png" border="0"/></a>
```

А есть еще пара ссылок при клике на которые загружаются новые изображения с помощью скрипта:

```
$("#knav1").click(function(){
        $("#navldesc").load('/api.php?nvl=y&komplektn=Комплит2');
});
```

Вид ссылок такой же как и выше, но лайтбокс с ними уже не работает. Думаю это из-за того что изначально их на странице нету. Как можно решить/обойти эту проблему?

Comment: переинициализировать DOM документ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Когда вы делаете `load`, вы обновляете `DOM` документ. Для того, чтобы сработал, его надо переинициализировать

```
('#navldesc').load('/api.php?nvl=y&komplektn=Комплит2',data,function(){
  $('a[rel*=lightbox]').lightbox();
});
```

Comment: не дочитал вам нужно вместо lightbox поставить slimbox вроде так инициализируется объект.

Comment: ".lightbox();" - это какое то событие?

Comment: почему slimbox? аттрибут rel="lightbox".

Comment: >обычный плагин Slimbox 2
Он хоть и пользует rel=lightbox но инициализируется через slimbox, посему получается правильная инициализация:

('#navldesc').load('/api.php?nvl=y&komplektn=Комплит2',data,function(){
  $('a[rel*=lightbox]').slimbox();
});

Comment: Спасибо за помощь.